# VB.net How to access row in 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I want to read all elements of the first row from a 2-D array in VB.NET. Is there a simple way to do it rather than running a loop. I know that in MATLAB there is possibilty to say: `A(1,:)` and its done.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built into the array itself to read without a loop but you could use a LINQ query, e.g.

```vb
Dim firstRow = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).
                          Select(Function(i) myArray(0, i))
```

Note that what is a "row" and what is a "column" is not defined for a 2D array so it's really up to you whether you want to use that or this:

```vb
Dim firstRow = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1).
                          Select(Function(i) myArray(i, 0))
```

That gives you an enumerable list of the specified elements so the question is, what do you want to do with it? You haven't actually specified. As it is, all you can really do is enumerate it, which means running a `For Each` loop over it. That kinda defeats the purpose of avoiding a loop in the first place. If you're saying, without actually saying, that you want those elements in a 1D array then you can call `ToArray`:

```vb
Dim firstRow = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).
                          Select(Function(i) myArray(0, i)).
                          ToArray()
```

EDIT:

Here is an extension method that you could use to do the job:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ArrayExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function GetRow(Of T)(source As T(,), rowIndex As Integer) As T()
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).
                          Select(Function(i) source(rowIndex, i)).
                          ToArray()
    End Function

End Module
```

It then makes the calling code much cleaner, especially if you need to do it multiple times, e.g.

```vb
Dim firstRow = myArray.GetRow(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. exactly this seems much more what i was looking for. Your last comment about converting to array completed it. Could you add further explanation on the first two methods you mentioned and what is the difference between the two.

Comment: @IrtazaWaheed, I have enhanced the answer with an extension method.

Comment: "what is the difference between the two" The first method assumes that the first index is the row, `myArray(0, i)`, and second index is the column.  The second method assumes the first index is the column and the second index is the row: `myArray(i, 0)`.  Note the `0` and `i` have been swapped in the two versions, and that the `GetUpperBound()` call is using either `1` or `0` to get either the number of columns or rows respectively.

Comment: *"Could you add further explanation on the first two methods you mentioned and what is the difference between the two"*. If you read the code then you can see the difference in the code. If you execute the code then you can see the difference in the behaviour. One of them gets a "row" and one of them gets a "column". Which one is which depends on your definitions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for the extension, would this method also work for jagged arrays?

Comment: *"would this method also work for jagged arrays"*. Why would you need it to? A jagged array is a 1D array of 1D arrays so I would think that most people would consider the first "row" of a jagged array to be the first inner array, so that is simply the first element of the outer array: `Dim firstRow = myJaggedArray(0)`. If what you actually want is an array containing the first element of each of the inner arrays then you could basically use the same code as the second snippet, replacing `myArray(i, 0)` with `myArray(i)(0)`. You can chain a `ToArray` call on the end if you want.

Comment: If you start with a jagged array, because it is actually a 1D array, you can simplify `myArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1` to `myArray.Length`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you a lot. If you could just like my question than that would be super :).

Comment: Excel, among others, have a lower bound of '1' not '0', so to keep the same index numbering you need to consider adding the extra element 'zero'.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know size of your array u can use nested loop For Each like this:

```
For each row in array
    For each col in row
    ''something here like Debug.Write(col.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

If you know your size and you want specific item in the array you simply do that like in any other loop "for" like this:

```
For index As Integer = 5 To 5
    For index2 As Integer = 3 To 3
        Debug.Write(index2.ToString)
    Next
Next
```